# Compatible filesystem that preserves linux permissions and times

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I have a `SSD` that stores my backups.
The backup files are mostly generated in my `Arch` linux.
I wonder what SSD filesystem can comply with these requirements:

a) preserves permissions and times of files copied from Linux
b) is most compatible with `Windows` and `Mac` OS

Comment: May I ask how the backups are being generated? It is rather a matter of how you create the backups and how you provide data for restoration than if the OS can directly see it.

Comment: Currently I use `cp` to move files to `SSD` from `Linux`. To backup only files that were modified later than last backup, I need to preserve `time-of-last-mod` attribute. I also store other files on `SSD` (photos) that need to be accessed from other `OSes`. A simple solution seems to be making more `SSD` partitions: one `ext4` for Linux files and other `NTFS` for photos. I wonder if `Windows` can detect the `NTFS` partition correctly in such a case.

Comment: All partitions are on the same dual-boot PC, I assume? A shared "data"-NTFS partition will be easily accessibly by both OSes, yet unix permissions won't be stored. Option 1 is as you suggested with two FSes, option 2 to see if you really need unix permissions in the backup, option 3 if you are OK with read-only access from Windows, there are ext-drivers available, option 4 backup to be put on a server in the network.